# I accidentally downloaded a Trojan:Win32/Occamy.C virus. I did not run the EXE. Am I safe?

Tags: virus, virus-removal, trojan

So I have just downloaded a Trojan virus on accident. I did not run the EXE, and now the file is gone (I don't know if I deleted it or not, but it isn't in my recycling bin.) I ran a McAfee security scan, and it says I'm safe. I searched for the files that usually get downloaded into your computer and found nothing. I have heard that it can run itself when you turn on the computer. Am I safe? I'm not turning off the computer until I know.

[image]

Comment: If you did not run the exe, you are most likely safe.

Comment: Why was this put on hold? My computer may be at stake.

Comment: @Yekult - We expect questions to be properly researched.  Windows Defender quarantined the malicious file.  Your screenshot indicates this fact.

Comment: I see. I deleted the quarantined file. Thanks for the help!